# Math.floor() not working for me

Tags: javascript, html

My Javascript File

```
function getValues_sft_r(val){
var numVal1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("sft_i").value);
var numVal2=(numVal1 / 5476);


document.getElementById("sft_r").value = math.floor(numVal2)
}
```

My HTML File
    
    
    
    Test Page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>

<style>
input.numbox{
width:30px;
height:20px;
}
input.mainbox{
width:30px;
height:20px;
font-size:30;
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

Convert SQ.Ft. to Ropani :
<br/>
Sq.Ft.:
<input class="numbox" type="text" id="sft_i" value="0" onkeyup="getValues_sft_r(1)" />

Ropani:
<input style="mainbox" id="sft_r" value="">

</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the `Math.floor(numVal2)` value in my HTML document. How should I do it to get the value?

Comment: Perhaps Math.round(..); instead of math.round(..)?

Comment: `Math.Floor()` does not appear even once in your code (and it would be incorrect if it did). Also, what do you mean by "I am not getting"...? Please edit your question so it is clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not seeing `Math.Floor()` in your code....

Answer (score 1):

Math has a capital letter and will therefore produce an error

Should be

```
Math.floor();
```

You might also want

```
class="mainbox"
```

Not

```
style="mainbox"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Math.round()** not **math.round()**

http://jsfiddle.net/hvty5/

```
function getValues_sft_r(val) {
    var numVal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sft_i").value);
    var numVal2 = (numVal1 / 5476);

    document.getElementById("sft_r").value = Math.round(numVal2)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the last post. It was my mistake. It's actually math.floor(); which I've edited already.